# No Access to SQL Server with Delphi FireDAC on UNIX

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ubuntu-18.04, firedac, unixodbc

I have an application running under Windows connecting to a SQL Server. The application works perfectly fine under Windows.
The same application should work likewise on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) via Delphi's cross-platform development.
Yet, I get the

[image: driver error message].

This happened after installation of the driver via Microsoft's tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Does someone have any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Maybe Firewall trouble? --> disable firewall temporarily on both client and server. Are they both in the same subnet?. Missing driver files? -->Did you distribute all the required firedac drivers and libs to the linux client? Using runtime libs or one monolithic app? Adding this info might help solving.

Comment: You should specify either a `Driver` or a `DSN` (data source name) in your connection string. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connection-string-keywords-and-data-source-names-dsns?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started developing my cross-platform FMX application that was supposed to work with SQL Server, I also used FireDAC in the beginning. But, when it came time to deploy my application on Linux, I ran into similar difficulties. I decided that configuring each client computer to install my application was too laborious and I switched to SDAC, which allows working directly with SQL Server not only on Windows but on Linux and macOS. Now I just need to copy my application, and it works everywhere without any additional settings. I advise you to try this option.